# Issue with Spider HighChart as it is showing as a line chart sometimes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am getting some problem with Spider HighChart as on one location it is showing as a line chart and on another location it is showing up as a spider chart.

I am using a very simple code from high chart library. is it something related to the section where chart type is line and chart polar is true.

please suggest what could be the error?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    credits:{enabled:false},
    chart: {
        polar: 'true',
        type: 'line',
        width: 850,
        height: 700
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Alliance Performance',
        x: 0
    },

    pane: {
        size: '80%'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['alliance with Company', 'The right people from both sides of the alliance', 'Decisions related to our alliance', 'Rationale for decisions demonstrates strong consideration of our business and our needs', 'Lessons learned are incorporated into work processes or practices', 'Expectations and deadlines', 'Critical information', 'When decisions are made, both parties have a clear understanding and alignment on the rationale'],
   labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '11px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
            width: 300

        }
    },            

    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'Top',
        verticalAlign: 'Top',
        y: 30,
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Employees',
        data: [3.1, 3.0, 3.1, 5.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.6, 4.5],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    },{
        name: 'Partners',
        data: [2.1, 4.0, 3.1, 4.0, 3.5, 2.0, 5.0, 4.6],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]

});
```

Comment: "it is showing as a line chart sometimes" means ? Is your chart sometime displayed with line chart and some time with spider chart ?

Answer (score 1):

Your char is displaying as line chart because "**highcharts-more.js**" is missing.

Once you add this script you chart will be displayed as spiderweb as you expect.

**For Example:**

***Including highcharts-more***
[image: Including highcharts-more]

***Missing highcharts-more***
[image: Missing highcharts-more]

Answer (score 0):

In the location where there is line chart, you miss the reference to the highcharts-more.js file. Please ensure that in both location you have attached all required files.